# Can I create ClickOnce without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net

If yes how or can point me to a resource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is GUI based Clickonce manifest creator available. If you google if you will find help to use this App. I have used this application to publish and compare Clickonce manifests. Here is the link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28VS.80%29.aspx
This link is also useful for manual Clickonce management : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx

Comment: Thanks for mentionning this tool

Answer (score 5):

MSDN has a full tutorial on doing it just from the command-line here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx

*Note:* the *first* section is how it's generated in the IDE, read beyond for how to do the build completely outside of Visual Studio.